# Ubuntu 14.04 + liblwgeom-2.1.1 postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu, geos

I had a project working on my computer and I've decided to update my ubuntu to 14.04 and my project stopped working =[

I'm using python/django and postgres and I use these libs:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

And now when I run some script that uses one of theses libs I got the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /get-menus-categorized/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bug/virtualenvs/menuchefs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bug/projects/menuchef/menuchef/core/views.py", line 985, in get_menus_categorized
    item = {'id':menu.id, 'title':menu.title, 'photo':menu.photo.url, 'description':menu.description, 'restaurant_slug':menu.restaurant.slug, 'number_of_likes':menu.number_of_likes}
  File "/home/bug/virtualenvs/menuchefs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 384, in __get__
    rel_obj = qs.get(**params)
  File "/home/bug/virtualenvs/menuchefs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 382, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/bug/virtualenvs/menuchefs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 90, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/bug/virtualenvs/menuchefs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/bug/virtualenvs/menuchefs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 775, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/home/bug/virtualenvs/menuchefs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/bug/virtualenvs/menuchefs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/bug/virtualenvs/menuchefs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 58, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/bug/virtualenvs/menuchefs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 54, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
DatabaseError: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so": /usr/lib/liblwgeom-2.1.2.so: undefined symbol: GEOSDelaunayTriangulation
```

I thinking about downgrade my ubuntu version. Any has a clue?

Comment: Looks like your upgrade didn't update PostGIS, so it's still linked to a version of `libgeos` that doesn't match what's on your system. Make sure you checked the sources.list entry for postgresql in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` - if it names the old distro version explicitly rather than using a placeholder you'll need to change the version and then `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after a standard `apt-get upgrade` which included postgis on PG 9.3.

```
Preparing to replace liblwgeom-2.1.2 2.1.2+dfsg-1.pgdg12.4+4 (using .../liblwgeom-2.1.2_2.1.3+dfsg-1.pgdg12.4+7_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement liblwgeom-2.1.2 ...
(...)
Preparing to replace postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts 2.1.2+dfsg-1.pgdg12.4+4 (using .../postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts_2.1.3+dfsg-3.pgdg12.4+2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts ...
Preparing to replace postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1-scripts 2.1.2+dfsg-1.pgdg12.4+4 (using .../postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1-scripts_2.1.3+dfsg-3.pgdg12.4+2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1-scripts ...
(...)
Setting up liblwgeom-2.1.2 (2.1.3+dfsg-1.pgdg12.4+7) ...
(...)
Setting up postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts (2.1.3+dfsg-3.pgdg12.4+2) ...
Setting up postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1-scripts (2.1.3+dfsg-3.pgdg12.4+2) ...
```

It appears that `liblwgeom-2.1.3.so` replaces the 2.1.2 version. Create a sym link in `/usr/lib` and it works again:

```
sudo ln -s liblwgeom-2.1.3.so liblwgeom-2.1.2.so
```

The extensions load and I can work with spatial data, but I have not done a thorough testing to see if everything still works as advertised (but backwards compatibility on a minor version upgrade should typically not be a problem).

Comment: I have this same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.13 and unfortunately this solution does not work.